# Проблемма перехода по ссылке в Firefox

Tags: php, firefox

Есть сайт на wp с использование wp globus , в chrome работает все корректно но в firefox при попытке отрыть главную по адрессу http://url.com он пытается открыть http://url.com/ru , и мы попадаем на 404, href у ссылки указан правильно но firefox дописывает в конец /ru и все , случается проблема только на главной , может кто сталкивался помогите